# HIbernate throws MappingException

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi,

I'm trying to do a simple app with Hibernate and Maven.
I've created hibernate.cfg.xml and mapping file contacts.hbm.xml.

**Once I start it I get an exception:**

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2241)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2158)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2137)
    at main.java.FirstHibernate.com.myhib.CRUDS.CrudsOps.main(CrudsOps.java:15)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 54; columnNumber: 129; Attribute "value" must be declared for element type "property".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.addDTDDefaultAttrsAndValidate(XMLDTDValidator.java:1253)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1917)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:763)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:353)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2715)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2238)
    ... 3 more
```

**Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  ~ Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java
  ~
  ~ Copyright (c) 2010, Red Hat Inc. or third-party contributors as
  ~ indicated by the @author tags or express copyright attribution
  ~ statements applied by the authors.  All third-party contributions are
  ~ distributed under license by Red Hat Inc.
  ~
  ~ This copyrighted material is made available to anyone wishing to use, modify,
  ~ copy, or redistribute it subject to the terms and conditions of the GNU
  ~ Lesser General Public License, as published by the Free Software Foundation.
  ~
  ~ This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  ~ but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY
  ~ or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU Lesser General Public License
  ~ for more details.
  ~
  ~ You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
  ~ along with this distribution; if not, write to:
  ~ Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  ~ 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor
  ~ Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
  -->
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">postgres</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider" />

        <property name="propertyName">value</property>

        <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
        <mapping resources="resources/hibernate/mapping/contacts.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping class="FirstHibernate.com.myhib.CRUDS.Contacts"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**contacts.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class table="contacts" lazy="false" name="FirstHibernate.com.myhib.CRUDS.Contacts">
        <id column="id" type="int" name="id">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <propetry name="fname" type="string" column="fname" />
        <propetry name="lname" type="string" column="lname" />
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

What can be a source of that exception?

P.S. Java classes could be posted if they are needed.

**--UPDATE--**

when I changed

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider"/>
```

to

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider</property>
```

I got such exception

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2241)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2158)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2137)
    at main.java.FirstHibernate.com.myhib.CRUDS.CrudsOps.main(CrudsOps.java:15)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 59; columnNumber: 76; Attribute "resources" must be declared for element type "mapping".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.addDTDDefaultAttrsAndValidate(XMLDTDValidator.java:1253)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1917)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:763)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:353)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2715)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2238)
    ... 3 more
```

**--UPDATE 2--**

Once I changed

*Are you sure it's  and not ? Because in the DTD I can only see 'resource' and not 'resources' attribute of the element 'mapping'. – Balázs Mária Németh 5 mins ago*

I got

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
    at org.hibernate.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:513)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:509)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:716)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2344)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2310)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2290)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2243)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2158)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2137)
    at main.java.FirstHibernate.com.myhib.CRUDS.CrudsOps.main(CrudsOps.java:15)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 20; Document root element "hibernate-mapping", must match DOCTYPE root "hibernate-configuration".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(XMLDTDValidator.java:1599)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1877)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:742)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:376)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3063)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:881)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:75)
    ... 11 more
```

**--UPDATE 3--**

That helped me

```
And finally it looks like there's a problem with contacts.hbm.xml. Change

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
to

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" 
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

Now I got such exception:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
    at org.hibernate.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:513)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:509)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:716)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2344)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2310)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2290)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2243)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2158)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2137)
    at main.java.FirstHibernate.com.myhib.CRUDS.CrudsOps.main(CrudsOps.java:15)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 63; Element type "propetry" must be declared.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1906)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:763)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:353)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2715)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:75)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: It's a typo: propetry! Change to property :) Try to understand what the exception says: 'Element type "propetry" must be declared'. That means that there is no such attribute as "propetry". Then you would have to look at it and you would see the typo!

Comment: oh! yep, that fixed error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [DTD](http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd).
The element `property` does not have an attribute `value`.
In similar cases when you encounter XML parsing errors, always have a look at the DTD or schema description!

So as PSR also said, change

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider"/>
```

and move the `value` as sub-element:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider</property>
```

Also it's `<mapping resources=""...>` and not `<mapping resource=""...>`. In the DTD I can only see `resource` and not `resources` attribute of the element `mapping`.

And finally it looks like there's a problem with `contacts.hbm.xml`. Change

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" 
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it is not correct

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider" />
```

change to

```
 <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"> org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider</property >
```

it doesn't have a "value" attribute

Answer (score 0):

add this text on top of hibernate.cfg.xml 
`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">`